# Installing pip on Mac OSX password issue

Tags: macos, sudo

I am learning Python and trying to install PIP. However, I keep reaching a password issue in the terminal. There seems to be a key symbol and does not allow me to type in my computer password. I'd appreciate any help.

[The python password issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCC4M.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/7976758 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/ Copy/paste from the terminal and properly format it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read.

Comment: Also the question is off-topic. It's not a question about Python or `pip`, it's a question about system administration.

Comment: With the next issue I have, I'll copy + paste. Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal when inputting your password it does not echo. Double check your typing as well.

If you really cannot get sudo to work, then boot the system into single user mode (COMMAND+S) and repeat your command.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, I appreciate it. Since pip is already included in MacOSX all I had to type in the terminal was pip3 install pyperclip